# Como obtener solo algunas Columnas DataTable c#

Tags: c#

```
        using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Archvios de Excel (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx| Excel 97-23 (*.xls)|*.xls";
            openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
            openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (var stream = File.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                    {
                        var dataset = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                        {
                            ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                            {
                                UseHeaderRow = true,
                            }
                        });

                         System.Data.DataTable datblaexcel = dataset.Tables[0];
```

un saludo a todos.

quiero seleccionar solo algunas columnas de un archivo de excel y no se como

pero en general lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

-crear una tabla (columna1,columna2,columna3,columna4,columna5)

- del archivo de Excel solo necesito 3 columnas
- las otras 2 las lleno mediante un update para obtener mi tabla con lo que necesito

no puedo modificar el excel antes de importarlo, tengo que importarlo con las columnas que no voy a usar.

entonces queria hacer algo asi como: importar el excel , seleccionar las columnas que necesito y agregarlas en la tabla que estoy construyendo.

muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Usas `FilterColumn` en la configuración, por ejemplo:

Mostrar las columnas 0, 2 y 5 (las columnas comienzan con el índice cero)

```
FilterColumn = (c,i) => i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 5
```

Mostrar las columnas pares

```
FilterColumn = (c,i) => i % 2 == 0
```

Mostrar las columnas mayores a 1 y menores a 5

```
FilterColumn = (c,i) => i>1 && i<5
```

Demo

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            
openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
openFileDialog.Filter = "Archvios de Excel (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx| Excel 97-23 (*.xls)|*.xls";
openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
               
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
                
using (var stream = File.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
{
    var dataset = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
    {
        ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
        {
            UseHeaderRow = true,
            FilterColumn = (c,i) => i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 5
        }
    });

    System.Data.DataTable datblaexcel = dataset.Tables[0];

}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, funciona también para un datatable? me puedes ayudar con lo siguiente : crear un datatable (tablaprincipal) con 6 columnas por ejemplo, llenar 4 columnas con el datatable que estoy sacando desde el excel (datblaexcel )  y las otras 2 que restan con un update que mas adelante lo voy a sacar.  yo tengo este proyecto en vfp9 y lo estoy migrando a c# que estoy aprendiendo de 0. en vfp 9 se me hace facil trabajar con cursores e ir llenadolos de otros cursores para optener la informacion que necesito pero en c# tengo dificultades para entender esa parte

Comment: seria asi como tener una tabla A y llenarla con informacion de una tabla B y una tabla C

Comment: @joeldanielColmenarez Existe algún motivo para que `A` deba ser un datatable ??? Pasa que un Datatable es en esencia una estructura para almacenar datos, es útil cuando la rellenas desde un Excel o un SQL, porque lo hace automático, pero su manipulación es engorrosa. En cambio una `List` (por dar un ejemplo) es todo lo contrario.

Comment: @joeldanielColmenarez En cualquier caso, lo que propones sería otra pregunta distinta, por lo que debes realizar una nueva publicación (recuerda agregar un código de lo que has intentado cuando la hagas). Además, si está respuesta ha contestado tu pregunta puedes marcarla como aceptada. Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias de verdad, con respecto a que si existe algun motivo para que A sea un datatable es por que desconozco sobre que usar, como habia comentado que estoy acostumbrado a trabajar con los cursores de VFP 9 que son como tablas temporales en memoria.